# remove application icon from the taskbar using .net with c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to show icon on the taskbar, well i did this in this way.

```
ResourceManager resManager = new ResourceManager("TestAgent.Properties.Resources", GetType().Module.Assembly);
                notifyicon.Icon = (Icon)resManager.GetObject("TestAgent");
                notifyicon.Visible = true;
                notifyicon.Text = "Test Agent";
                this.Hide();
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                this.SetVisibleCore(false);
```

On other side when try remove icon from the taskbar doing in this way.

```
notifyicon.Visible = false;
            notifyicon = null;
            rulehandler = null;
```

I did this successfully but the problem is when try to remove icon from the taskbar it remove icon successfully from the taskbar but not hide the icon, When hover the mouse on the icon it removes.

Is there anyway to remove icon without mouse hover?
I am doing this in windows form with c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Dispose it.

In a Windows Form you can subscribe to the global event ApplicationExit ...

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);

private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     notifyicon.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This event is not fired when i clicked on applicaion stop button?

Comment: dispose the notifyIcon from the stop button's click event.

Comment: where do you put the         Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit); ?

Comment: After InitializeComponent in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

simply write `notifyIcon.Visible = false;` (capital I in Icon) before closing the window, and you are good to go. 
As simple as that.